# Упаковка данных для отправки в com порт python

Tags: python, нагрузочное-тестирование, com-port

Вопрос в следующем
Написан модуль для подсчета crc для нагрузочной платы

```
  class CrcCalc:
def __init__(self):
    msk_11_4 = 0x0810
    msk_0 = 0x0001
    msk_data = 0x80
    msk_15 = 0x8000
    high = 1
    low = 0
    self.started = False
    self.Escaped = False
    self.packet = ' '
    self.CRC_END = '\xc0'
    self.CRC_ESC = '\xdb'
    self.CRC_ESC_END = '\xdc'
    self.CRC_ESC_ESC = '\xdd'

def __getcrc(self, buf):
    msk_11_4 = 0x0810
   # msk_0 = 0x0001
   # msk_data = 0x80
    msk_15 = 0x8000
    crc = 0xffff
    j=0
    k = j
    j += 1
    for k  in buf[k]:
        data = buf[ord(k)]
        i = 0
        while i <= 7:
            data << 1
            crc_15 = crc & msk_15
            if (data & msk_15):
                flag = crc_15
                flag = 0 if crc_15 == msk_15 else msk_15
            else:
                flag = crc_15
            if (flag):
                crc = ((msk_11_4 ^ crc) << 1) | 1
            else:
                crc << 1

    return crc`
```

И нужно отправить в ком порт следующую последовательность байт
     90 b8 00 00 07 55 a4 7b 00 da 03 02 05 01 
где первые два байта это crc заголовка (90 b8) заголовок (00 00 07 55 a4) crc блока данных (55 a4) и сам блок данных (7b 00 da 03 02 05 01) и нужно получить ответ в виде 39 6d 00 20
 через команду serial.write() и serial.read() данные отправляются, но плата не отвечает, подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, и как грамотно реализовать упаковку данных и ее отправку в порт, тк питон я изучаю не так давно. Заранее спасибо

P.s данные, которые приходят должны пройти проверку crc через выше приведенный код, переменная buf это одномерный массив, который должен заполняться со сдвигом, в оригинале же этот код был написан на си предыдущим программистом и выглядел вот так

```
 ComPort1->Receive(ReceiveBuf);

 buf[7] = WeigandAddress;
 buf[8] = 0x00;
 buf[9] = 0xDA;
 buf[10] = 0x03;
 buf[11] = 0x02;
 buf[12] = ReaderNum;
 buf[13] = LOW;

 crc = CrcCalc(buf+7, 7);

 buf[5] = (unsigned char)(crc >> 8);
 buf[6] = (unsigned char)(crc & 0x00FF);
 buf[4] = 0x07;
 buf[3] = 0x00;
 buf[2] = CommandCounter;

 crc = CrcCalc(buf+2, 5);

 buf[0] = (unsigned char)(crc >> 8);
 buf[1] = (unsigned char)(crc & 0xFFFF);

 for(i=0; i<14; i++)
 {
   sprintf(symbol, " %0X", buf[i]);
   if(i == 0) strcpy(str, symbol);
   else strcat(str, symbol);
 }
 Memo1->Lines->Add(str);

 ComPort1->Send(buf, 14);
 Sleep(100);
 size = ComPort1->Receive(ReceiveBuf);

 sprintf(str, "%X", CommandCounter);
 Panel1->Caption = str;

 if(CommandCounter != 0xFF) CommandCounter++;
 else CommandCounter = 1;
```

Comment: Попробуйте создать  самодостаточный минимальный пример кода (запишите вывод Си кода в файл, сравните с выводом Питон-кода)¶ В сторону: чтобы посмотреть как формирование [сетевых] пакетов в Питоне может выглядеть, можно поиграться [со scapy](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#interactive-tutorial) (это просто, чтобы представлять как идиоматический интерфейс выглядит)¶ Попробуйте bytearray(), поиграйтесь с преобразованием из int в bytes и обратно, обратите внимание на разницу между побитовыми операциями в Си и Питоне, познакомьтесь со struct модулем, ctypes.Structure.